# Trying to iterate over json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm trying to iterate over this json encoded array which is a string:

```
"{"":{"count":{"total":112,"open":0,
"solved":0,
"deleted":106,
"closed":6},
"average_time_open_in_minutes":206,
"tickets_fortnight_week_count":11,
"tickets_last_week_count":15,"trend":1},
"Net2grid":{"count":"total":8,"open":0,"solved":0,"deleted":8},"average_time_open_in_minutes":0,"tickets_fortnight_week_count":0,"tickets_last_week_count":0,"trend":0},"Closed_by_merge":{"count":{"total":2,"open":0,"solved":0,"closed":2},"average_time_open_in_minutes":502,"tickets_fortnight_week_count":0,"tickets_last_week_count":0,"trend":0},"Analytics":{"count":{"total":1,"open":0,"solved":0,"deleted":1},"average_time_open_in_minutes":26,"tickets_fortnight_week_count":0,"tickets_last_week_count":0,"trend":0},"Meter":{"count":{"total":5,"open":5,"solved":0},"average_time_open_in_minutes":0,"tickets_fortnight_week_count":0,"tickets_last_week_count":2,"trend":1},"Installation":{"count":{"total":8,"open":5,"solved":3},"average_time_open_in_minutes":404,"tickets_fortnight_week_count":0,"tickets_last_week_count":0,"trend":0},"Other...":{"count":{"total":3,"open":2,"solved":1},"average_time_open_in_minutes":39,"tickets_fortnight_week_count":0,"tickets_last_week_count":0,"trend":0},"Meter Offline":{"count":{"total":8,"open":7,"solved":1},"average_time_open_in_minutes":8,"tickets_fortnight_week_count":0,"tickets_last_week_count":0,"trend":0},"App Usage":{"count":{"total":6,"open":5,"solved":0,"deleted":1},"average_time_open_in_minutes":8,"tickets_fortnight_week_count":0,"tickets_last_week_count":0,"trend":0}}"
```

An ajax call returns that string and i'm trying to only get the keys like: "app usage" and "Meter Offline" to return like so:

```
$.get('/ajax/ticket-and-notes-data.php', function (data) {

            var problems = getProblems(data);

            function getProblems(problems) {
                var problemCategories = [];
                $.each(JSON.parse(problems), function (key, value) {
                    if (key != "") {
                        problemCategories.push = key;
                    }
                });
                return problemCategories;
            }
        });
```

But I can't get the keys to go into the problemCategories.

I use this to set the categories in a highchart bubble chart and I will use more of the data from the string later.

I need to get this to work first.

Comment: `problemCategories.push(key)` ?

Comment: That does not appear to be valid JSON.

Comment: JSON string is invalid

Comment: actually it is valid and it works now due to the answer of Dylan Hamilton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in the way that you're using array.push. You should use `array.push(item)` instead of `array.push = item`.

Comment: That's it, damn I hate myself for missing such a simple thing